# Can't see photos on Windows 6 phone

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I have photos on a Windows 6 phone which I want to copy onto my PC.  When I plug the USB cable in, Windows Explorer pops-up and shows the file structure on drive E:.

However the folder structure doesn't seem to match what is on the phone.  And when I list all pictures with this filter: `*.jpg`, the photos I want to transfer aren't showing.  The strange thing is, some old photos taken a while ago ARE showing.  It just happens that the recent photos aren't showing.

I have a feeling that somehow, what Windows Explorer is pointing to is somewhere else on the phone.

I've tried importing the photos using the import feature on Windows 7 but it imports photos from a different folder, not the photos in the folder I want to transfer.  I've read Windows Mobile Device Center might work but it's just showing "not connected".

Comment: Bwah, sorry. I voted to close, but actually your question *is* on-topic since it's about interfacing with your computer.

Answer (score 1):

On my WM6.5 phone, there's a choice between "ActiveSync" vs "Disk Drive (faster file transfer)" meaning USB mass storage mode.  But note that mass-storage mode only gives access to the microSD card content, not files on the phone's internal memory.

So make sure this setting is set to ActiveSync.  The failure of WMDC to recognize the device suggests that you're in Mass Storage mode currently.

The option is found under Settings -> Connections -> USB to PC.